# Wordpress Hide wp-admin to admin with Nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I would like to redirect `example.com/wp-admin` to my index and make the WP-Admin accessible though something like `example.com/admin`.

I did this in `apache` but after switching to nginx I don't know how to do this?.

Is there a way to do this without changing any of the wordpress files but changing the nginx config ?
Also need to access `example.com/wp-admin/index.php` as `example.com/admin/index.php`, `example.com/wp-admin/posts.php` as `example.com/admin/posts.php` etc..

Comment: In my opinion if you use plugin than it will find security holes in your WordPress.

Comment: yes, i am also trying to do that

Comment: check the link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/wordpress-hide-wp-admin-with-nginx

Comment: @DeepKakkar it's already tried. it works only for entering example.com/admin/. no others like, if we enter example.com/admin/index.php it return "Not found"

Comment: then you should url redirection. just edited answer

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion if you use plugin than it will find security holes in your WordPress.

You can use the following steps to create your own URL of login either admin or else as follows:

1.) Add constant to `wp-confing.php`

```
define('WP_ADMIN_DIR', 'secret-folder');
define( 'ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', SITECOOKIEPATH . WP_ADMIN_DIR);
```

2.) Add below filter to `functions.php`

```
add_filter('site_url',  'wpadmin_filter', 10, 3);

function wpadmin_filter( $url, $path, $orig_scheme ) {
  $old  = array( "/(wp-admin)/");
  $admin_dir = WP_ADMIN_DIR;
  $new  = array($admin_dir);
  return preg_replace( $old, $new, $url, 1);
}
```

3.) Add below line to .htaccess file if you are using Apache

```
RewriteRule ^secret-folder/(.*) wp-admin/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Edit the Nginx virtual host file and place the following:

```
location ~* /admin/ {
  rewrite ^/admin/(.*) /wp-admin/$1 last;
}
```

Done...!!!

Now your admin URL will be like: http://www.yourdomain.com/secret-folder/

and the below code will restrict the URL: site.com/wp-admin

```
add_action('login_form','redirect_wp_admin');

function redirect_wp_admin(){
  $redirect_to = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

  if(count($_REQUEST)> 0 && array_key_exists('redirect_to', $_REQUEST)){
    $redirect_to = $_REQUEST['redirect_to'];
    $check_wp_admin = stristr($redirect_to, 'wp-admin');
    if($check_wp_admin){
      wp_safe_redirect( '404.php' );
    }
  }
}
```

Edited:
Edit the Nginx virtual host file and place the following:

```
location ~* /admin/ {
  rewrite ^/admin/(.*) /wp-admin/$1 last;
}
```

In case if you want to redirect url from index.php to back on admin

```
server {
  index index.php;

  if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php$") {
    return 301 $1;
  }

  location = /admin/index.php {
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com/admin/;
  }
}
```

Another benefit from doing it this way is that `nginx` does a return faster than a rewrite.

Comment: It's works when i was using `Appache`, but now i moved to `NGINX`. Then it's not not working now.

Comment: The preferred method is to use NO IF-STMTS: Try with # Login Short Cut
location ~* /login/ {
    rewrite ^/login/(.*)? /wp-admin/$1;
}

Comment: it's already applied. it works only for entering `example.com/admin/`. no others like, if we enter `example.com/admin/index.php` it return "Not found"

Comment: what are you getting with admin/index.php , 404 or else ? I have a link for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591258/remove-index-php-from-url-only-on-root-with-nginx-rewrite hope this help.

Comment: Not working anymore. Checked at both apache and nginx

Comment: Has anyone got the admin subfiles working like posts.php, edit.php, upload.php to not show an nginx 404? Or do we need to manually specify the admin URLs in an external conf file

Answer (score 0):

You mean to change the url of wp-admin. Then you can use a plugin mentioned below
[Wordpress Link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hc-custom-wp-admin-url/)

After installing the plugin Under settings->Permalink we can change WP-admin page slug to what we need.

Comment: add some details on here. Links will be disappear  after some times

Comment: After installing the plugin Under settings->Permalink we can change WP-admin page slug to what we need.

Answer (score -1):

For changing the admin url ,Try using the below plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/

Comment: actually i need to just replace `wp-admin` name in the URL to `admin`